# DNS treats IP address as hostname

Tags: performance, dns, ip

I have 2 servers in the same LAN, which are hosted by hosting.com with its dns servers.

When I sent an http request from httpBuilder on machine A with destination(machine B) IP address, like RESTClient(http://XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX/foo/bar), somehow in the DNS log shows the IP address was append with suffix like sna.hosting.com. So basically, a DNS query "XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX.static.sna.hosting.com" was sent, and obviously A/AAAA returned, which cost a very long time.

The question is why an IP address will still go to DNS query.

The hosts file on both machines are clean. The resolve.conf file on both machines just contain the dns servers ip.

One solution is just putting mapping entry in local hosts file, which works for this case but might not be long term one.

Any fresh thoughts?

Comment: Can you show the code using the send the request?

Comment: Just one line code: rest = new RESTClient(URI), then rest.post(path, body, requestContentType, contentType).  the URI here is specified with ip address

Comment: I'm not too familiar with httpbuilder, but if `RESTClient` is only accepting a URI then what you're seeing would make sense, as an IP is not a URI.

Comment: Based on some more research, it looks like the `RESTClient` constructor is not designed to take an IP. See [the documentation](http://groovy.codehaus.org/modules/http-builder/apidocs/groovyx/net/http/RESTClient.html#RESTClient%28java.lang.Object%29).

Comment: Well, IP is qualified for URI, like http://XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX/foo/bar RESTClient extends httpBuilder. thanks for your thoughts

Comment: Yeah it'll still work, but from a technical perspective an IP isn't a URI (as a URI is very specifically a string).

Comment: it's not just IP, it's ip with request path. should be fine

Comment: Thanks admdrew! I clarify the question for future guys

Answer (score 0):

This is because the hostname of both servers are set to an IP address. So the DNS server treats it as a FQDN. Solution is to assign the hostname with real hostnames.

Comment: An hostname is not an IP address. And a DNS server treats nothing as something else, it just has a list of records and replies for queries on those records.